# Strange port behavior (PIC24F)

Tags: pic, mplab, pickit, io

I was just trying to get port IO working with this code:

```
#include "p24Fxxxx.h" // This header will choose the right device header

#define FCY 16000000UL // Running at 16 MIPS = Fosc/2

#include <PIC24F_plib.h>
#include <libpic30.h>

// Configuration setup
_CONFIG1( FWDTEN_OFF & GWRP_OFF & GCP_OFF & JTAGEN_OFF & ICS_PGx3 )
_CONFIG2( FCKSM_CSDCMD & OSCIOFNC_ON & POSCMOD_HS & FNOSC_FRCPLL & I2C1SEL_PRI & PLL96MHZ_ON & PLLDIV_NODIV & IESO_OFF & IOL1WAY_OFF );
_CONFIG3( SOSCSEL_IO );

int main() {
    TRISB = 0;
    PORTB = 0;

    PORTBbits.RB0 = 1;
    PORTBbits.RB4 = 1;

    while(1) {
        __delay_ms( 200 );
    }
}
```

So I breakpoint on the `__delay_ms` instruction, and take a peek at the LATB registers:

[image]

(As pictured, only `LATB4` is switched on - confirmed with a multimeter)

Also, if I comment out the `PORTBbits.RB4 = 1;` line, `LATB0` is turned on (but not `LATB4`)

Is the second call overwriting it somehow? Maybe, because `PORTB = 0b10001;` alone works.

I'm using a PIC24FJ64GB002, MPLAB X, C30 and a PICkit 3. I realise that MPLAB X isn't 100% stable - but something *this* simple should work.

If some PIC guru could point me in the right direction, that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `PORTxbits.RBx` rather use `LATxbits.LATx`, when you set/reset your pins to avoid this problem.

Comment: Ah, that's it! Awesome!

Comment: `;)` had the same problem myself a while ago...

Answer (score 2):

Writing to an element of a bitfield will generally cause a read-modify-write operation to be performed. In particular, the line

```
PORTBbits.RB4 = 1;
```

will have the same behavior as

```
PORTB = PORTB | (1<<4);
```

My PIC is a bit rusty, but I believe that reading `PORTB` will return the current state of the pins, rather than the value last written?

Comment: This is correct. So if you set two pins in rapid succession, the first pin does not have time to rise above the input threshold. Therefore, since the second operation reads back the *physical* state of the pin, and the pin has not changed state yet, the second operation clobbers the first.

Comment: Ah, I get it now.